# Which is the fastest loop condition in .NET Framework?

Tags: c#

Comparing the loop conditions in .NET Framework, there are different ways to create the same loops, but in which cases are recommended each one of them.

```
// The foreach and .ForEach are pretty much the same scenario.
foreach(var item in itemList) { // do something }
itemList.ForEach(item => { // do something });

// Is more primitive, so is usually faster.
for(var i=0; i<itemList.count;i++) { i++; // do something }
while (count < itemList.Count) { count++; // do something }
```

Comment: Why don't you measure yourself? People are usually say; [Horses are always fastest](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Comment: `for` and/or `whilte` are the fastest, because they don't use enumerators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the stopwatch class, for example:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
     Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopWatch.Start();
            foreach(var item in itemList) {...}
            stopWatch.Stop();
```

This will give you the time for each one of the loops